# How to not use the embedded console of pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

i would like to have a separate window open for the ouput of the console, like when i run my program without pycharm instead of the output going in the "run" tab of pycharm.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all you didn't provide the information, I would have loved to see which OS you use or what are your preferences for visualizing your output which really needed to solve your problem so I'll answer your question generally.

1. If you are using windows you can use the command prompt also called the cmd to run your python file, using a simple `WinKey + R` and then writing `cmd` which will open a simple Command Prompt, then you will need to navigate to your python file path with the command `cd` which you can read about in the internet and then run `python file_name` or `python3 file_name` depending on what you have, this will give you your code output.
2. Using linux dist it will be very similar to the windows one pressing `ALT+T` will open the terminal for you which is like the twin brother for your `cmd` and then you'll need to follow the `cd` step and further in my first note.

Both ways will give you to run your code and will show you the output of your code without using pycharm.

Hope I helped :)